# Error while reading bq table in Java eclipse - How do I get jar file for com/google/cloud/http/HttpTransportOptions package?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, jar, google-bigquery

I am trying to read a sample table from bq to java eclipse(on prem). I am stuck on an error which says class not found - HttpTransportOptions.
I know i am missing some dependencies. Which is the jar file that would cover this package?
The code is below:

```
    public class sample_bq_java {
          public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
            BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("project_id")
                    .setCredentials(
                            ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\3401770\\Downloads\\key.json"))
                    ).build().getService();
            String datasetName = "hacker_news.comments";
    
            // Fetches the dataset
    
            Dataset dataset = bigquery.getDataset(datasetName);
    
    
            System.out.printf("Dataset %s fetched.%n", dataset.getDatasetId().getDataset());
          }
    }
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/http/HttpTransportOptions
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions.getDefaultHttpTransportOptions(BigQueryOptions.java:114)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions$BigQueryDefaults.getDefaultTransportOptions(BigQueryOptions.java:109)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.<init>(ServiceOptions.java:305)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions.<init>(BigQueryOptions.java:91)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions.<init>(BigQueryOptions.java:30)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions$Builder.build(BigQueryOptions.java:86)
    at frcst.apps.stof.sample_bq_java.main(sample_bq_java.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that `HttpTransportOptions` [class](https://github.com/googleapis/java-core/tree/master/google-cloud-core-http/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/http) is a part of `google-cloud-core-http` [package](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-core-http) as for GCP Core http module implementation.

Just ensure that you've included `google-cloud-core-http-1.93.x.jar` into the project or add dependency in `pom.xml` file, fetching the package from the particular repository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-core-http</artifactId>
    <version>1.93.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have included `google-cloud-http-1.93.7` jar in the project. I have added it externally to my project's referenced libraries.

Comment: Above thing worked. Thanks. 
But I am facing with this new error -` java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiClientHeaderProvider$Builder.setQuotaProjectIdToken `

 I have already included ` gax-1.57.1. jar` in the project that has this package `com.google.api.gax.rpc`  which has the method `setQuotaProjectIdToken` already. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Glad to help here. If you find the answer sufficient consider [accept/up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) vote it as well. Meanwhile I do suggest to [open](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) the new Stack thread for the issue that you're mentioning in the comment as it is out of context for the parent case here